Syntax for defining a function that inputs a vector on ti-nspire?
I am trying to define a formula that simply inputs a vector and outputs its magnitude on the TI-nspire CX II. I know it might not save that much time, but I would like to know this information to do other vector arithmetic in the future.
I tried the following with the following errors:
mag([a,b]):=sqrt(a^2+b^2)
error: Argument must be a variable name
mag[a,b]:=sqrt(a^2+b^2)
error: Index out of range
mag([a b]):=sqrt(a^2+b^2)
error: Argument must be a variable name
mag[a b]:=sqrt(a^2+b^2)
error: Index out of range
I was expecting an output of "Done" on the bottom right.

It would be
mag(vect):= sqrt(vect[1,1]^2+vect[1,2]^2)


Please format the function correctly; thanks.

mag(v1):=sum(v1^2)^(1/2)

would work good any size of list
